# Need help for abs function?

Tags: sql, mariadb

If I write

```
abs((sum(daily_well_details.RegValue)
/ (sum(daily_well_details.Value*daily_well_details.Quantity)
+ sum(daily_well_details.RegValue))*100)) as accuracy
```

NO ERROR - RESULTS OK

As final result I'd need to have (100 - accuracy)

I tried several syntax but always get the error message "...#HI000Invalid use of group function...."

```
SELECT....
ABS(sum(100-(sum(daily_well_details.RegValue)
/ (sum(daily_well_details.Value*daily_well_details.Quantity)
+ sum(daily_well_details.RegValue))*100))) as accuracy
```

Comment: You can not use aggregate function inside of another aggregate - SUM(SUM(X)) = Error.

Answer (score 0):

You can instead use

```
SELECT.... ABS(100-(sum(daily_well_details.RegValue))/(sum(daily_well_details.Value*daily_well_details.Quantity))+(sum(daily_well_details.RegValue))*100))) as accuracy
```